# Can't get C++14 using XCode 7.0.1

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++14

I'm trying to use C++14 in XCode 7.0.1 and it's not working. I'm trying to use a std::string literal and I'm getting the error:

```
Invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier.
```

Since this is supposed to use C++14 why am I getting this error? I tried looking all around XCode for a setting or something but I can't find anything. I also tried looking online for answers but all the answers relate to earlier versions of XCode.

Here's a pic:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hawW8.png)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try changing the "C++ Language Dialect" setting in your Build Settings. Right now it is probably set at C++11 but should be changed to C++14.

[image]

Should be:

[image]