# Generic lambda xcode 8.3.3

Tags: c++, xcode, lambda

I was just trying to learn some features of lambda 
Tried one of the example provided here

[How does generic lambda work in C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233547/how-does-generic-lambda-work-in-c14)

```
auto glambda = [](auto a) { return a; };
```

But I don't know for some reason xcode complains about it

[image: auto not allowed in lambda parameter]

> auto not allowed in lambda parameter

1) Something I am missing in the installation or library

*Will Appreciate justification  for any down vote*

Comment: Did you enable c++14 in the project settings? The code above compiles for me.

Comment: @combinatorial any specific thing to do ..how did you do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358313/cant-get-c14-using-xcode-7-0-1

Comment: @WindyFields   Thanks for the link .But I don't see build setting in xcode ..I did look into that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your project in the left-hand panel in Xcode. Then choose the Build Settings tab. Type "C++ Language" in the filter at the top right. And then change the setting for the dialect to C++14 or GNU++14.

[image: Where to change the compiler setting to enable C++14]

Comment: Great it worked thanks a lot . I think your answer is more helpful for a new user of xcode like me. has more info then  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358313/cant-get-c14-using-xcode-7-0-1