# On Xcode, how to change the default compiler LLVM to g++-7

Tags: xcode, g++, llvm

Under the build settings, I tried to add g++-7 to the "change compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" section but failed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663426/generic-lambda-xcode-8-3-3

Comment: I see. Many thanks!